# Not sending errors to Firebase Crashlytics Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, crashlytics

I made an error handler as well as sending errors to Firebase Crashlytics. Errors are being passed around, but I'm running into an issue that errors aren't showing up in Firebase Crashlytics. I understand that errors are not sent to Firebase, but I can not understand why, can you tell me what the problem is and how to solve it? Check it out on an android emulator

**htt_service**

```
 } on DioError catch (e) {
  if (e.response != null) {
    ApiErrorHelper.handleError(e.response!.statusCode!, e, e.stackTrace!);
  }
```

**ApiErrorHelper**

```
static void handleError(
      int statusCode, dynamic error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    CrashlyticsService.recordError(error, stackTrace);
  }
```

**CrashlyticsService**

```
class CrashlyticsService {
  static void initializeCrashlytics() {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      return;
    }

    // Pass all uncaught errors from the framework to Crashlytics.
    final originalOnError = FlutterError.onError;
    FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails errorDetails) async {
      await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError(errorDetails);
      originalOnError!(errorDetails);
    };
  }

  static Future<void> recordError(dynamic error, StackTrace stackTrace) async {
    await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stackTrace);
  }
}
```